# Wrong usage of std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is a chunk of code how i implemented a linked list to traverse with the currentElem Pointer through my Game-Options.
This code is working well. However, just for testing purposes i wrote to a LogFile from the destructor of the OptionElem-Class so i could count how many OptionElem objects have been instantiated all together.
There are 9 Entrys in the Logfile. So 9 Objects have been instantiated and destroyed. I expected only 3 objects (e1, e2 and e3), because
i instantiated them once in the GameState constructor and then moved them to the optionElems-vector. I dont understand where the other 6 OptionElem objects have been instantiated.

```
#include "OptionElem.h"
#include <vector>
class GameState
    {
    std::vector<OptionElem> optionElems;
    OptionElem*        currentElem; 
    public:
    GameState(); 
    };

GameState::GameState()
    {
    OptionElem e1("Start Game"); 
    optionElems.push_back(std::move(e1)); 
    OptionElem e2("Options");
    optionElems.push_back(std::move(e2));   
    OptionElem e3("Exit");
    optionElems.push_back(std::move(e3));

    optionElems[0].Connect(optionElems[1]);
    optionElems[1].Connect(optionElems[2]);

    currentElem = &optionElems[0];
    }
```

Edit: 
I changed the lines

```
OptionElem e1("Start Game"); 
optionElems.push_back(std::move(e1));
```

to:

```
optionElems.emplace_back("Start Game");
```

and did the same change to the similar code below as suggested by sftrabbit and the Logfile changed to 3 entries, so only 3 OptionElem objects gets instantiated when using the emplace_back method instead moving the local variables to the vector. I consider this as more efficient since less objects get instantiated for the same operation (adding them to a vector)

Comment: Why are you bothering with reimplementing linked list inside one of your types - isn't storing iterator to current option enough?

Comment: @aryjczyk Or even an index would do. Can you explain your reason for "connecting" the options, Grundkurs?

Comment: But isn't an iterator a bit cleaner approach than an int?

Comment: @aryjczyk Sure, I'm just saying even an `int` would be nicer than this strange linked list approach. What they're doing doesn't have any of the benefits of a linked list.

Comment: If there will only ever be 3 elements, you should probably use a `std::array`: `std::array<OptionElem, 3> options; Gamestate() : options{"Start Game", "Options", "Exit"} { currentElem = &options[0]; }`. If options might be added after construction, you should be using in index for `currentElem` instead of a pointer that will be invalidated when the vector resizes.

Comment: @aryczyk: I didn't use an iterator for this because i didn't come to the idea to do so. Now i read it, it suddenly sounds like a good approach to do so. I just used a pointer because it works well and im kind of used to because i worked a lot with linked lists when learning c++. sftrabbit: Your hint using emplace_back worked well and reduced the instantiated objects from 9 to 3, i already edited my question, thanks. I connected them so i can traverse with the currentElem-Pointer from object to object when pressing a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving an object doesn't make that object magically disappear. It just steals the contents of the object (if the move constructor is implemented properly, that is) to put in the new object. The original object still exists and should eventually be destroyed, and each move still involves the construction of another object which will also eventually be destroyed.

Perhaps it's a problem with the word "move". It doesn't really involve moving the object in memory - what it really involves is moving the contents of the object to the new object.

Anyway, you might be interested in the `emplace_back` function which constructs vector elements in place:

```
optionElems.emplace_back("Start Game");
optionElems.emplace_back("Options");
optionElems.emplace_back("Exit");
```

Or even just initialising your `std::vector` like so:

```
std::vector<OptionElem> optionElems = {"Start Game", "Options", "Exit"};
```

---

A brief note on naming conventions: calling a collection `somethingElems` is putting information about the type in the name. You could just call it `options` and it's obvious that it has elements because it's plural (without saying `Elems`). Then `currentElem` would be called `currentOption`, which is much more understandable, right?

Comment: thanks for the super-fast response! So moving the OptionElem objects to the vector doesn't make any sense in my case since im not dealing with non-copyable objects like std::unique_ptr's and im still creating new objects with the move-command (what i wanted to avoid).

Comment: @Grundkurs Well it usually makes sense to do it when you can. The point of moving is not to avoid having too many objects, but to avoid *copying* too many objects. A move is generally more efficient than a copy.

Comment: +1 also, `optionsElems.reserve(3);` before those lines to prevent the vector from resizing

Comment: +1 for a clean, non-silly way of writing C++ code. If all the world's useless local variables were to go away, we could probably stop researching all this quantum storage stuff.

Comment: @Praetorian In general yeah, but in the case of constructing a menu it probably doesn't matter

Comment: @Grundkurs If you want to avoid making unnecessary objects, use the final approach I've given you, which immediately initialises the elements of the vector.

Comment: @aryjczyk Oh I wasn't thinking of performance; it was an attempt to preempt the next question where the OP, despite having called `emplace_back`, was still looking at more than 3 destructor calls :)